# Firebase signInSuccessWithAuthResult not called

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth for my website and I ran into a problem. I want to avoid the automatic redirect after signing in and as far as I know, if you return false in the callback it won't redirect. My problem is that the [signInSuccessWithAuthResult](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#signinsuccesswithauthresultauthresult-redirecturl) callback is not called. Why is it not called and is there a better way to achieve this?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
 var uiConfig = {
    callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
          // User successfully signed in.
          console.log("sign in success");
          // don't redirect automatically
          return false;
        }
    },
    signInSuccessUrl: <I dont want to go here>,
    signInOptions: [
      // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    // Terms of service url.
    tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>',
    // Privacy policy url.
    privacyPolicyUrl: '<your-privacy-policy-url>'
};

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
          user.getIdToken().then(function (accessToken) {
              console.log("token retrieved: "+accessToken);
              // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.open('POST', '/');
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
              xhr.onload = function() {
                console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
                document.getElementById('firebaseui-auth-container').hidden=true;
              };
              xhr.send('token=' + accessToken);
           });
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: It should trigger. Your code looks fine. Do you have an `onAuthStateChanged` listener setup that redirects or something? More information would be helpful to help debug your issue.

Comment: Yes, I did have an onAuthStateChanged listener, but it doesn't redirect. I added it to my question. The onAuthStateChanged listener is called correctly every time

Comment: "as far as I know...." - where did you get this info about returning false?  It seems to me that after the success/fail, firebase 'needs' to redirect and you should do that (I can't think of a great reason not to, really, but perhaps you have one...).  I answered a similar question yesterday with my code that works (directly from my app with comments, etc.) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954047/firebase-auth-js-php/51956711#51956711 perhaps will help.  (if you are trying to just stay on the same page, you might also try 'redirecting' back to the same page??)

Comment: _If the callback returns true, then the page is automatically redirected depending on the case:

If no signInSuccessUrl parameter was given in the URL (See: Overwriting the sign-in success URL) then the default signInSuccessUrl in config is used.
If the value is provided in the URL, that value will be used instead of the static signInSuccessUrl in config.
If the callback returns false or nothing, the page is not automatically redirected._ [readme of the firebase github](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#signinsuccesswithauthresultauthresult-redirecturl)

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code. I speculate you are using an older version of firebaseui-web where `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` was not yet supported. Previously `signInSuccess` was used but that is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following @bojeil tip, I updated the library and now it is working.

Note that the page is still reloading after signing in.

Comment: Which version of the library are you currently using?

Comment: which versions?