# Access Firebase Storage Media Object with PHP and Firebase Auth

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, google-api-php-client

In a project I am provided with API endpoints from a Firebase DB.

To retrieve data I authenticate a user with email and password (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password) and then sign every API call with the token. (These users are set up in Firebase DB)

Now one of the API endpoints returns Firebase Storage objects like this:

```
    "fileReferences": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "name": "images\/-s0m31D\/picture.jpg",
            "mediaLink": "https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/download\/storage\/v1\/b\/BUCKET.appspot.com\/o\/images%2F-s0m31D%2Fpicture.jpg?generation=1537959346600572&amp;alt=media",
            "selfLink": "https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/storage\/v1\/b\/BUCKET.appspot.com\/o\/images%2F-s0m31D%2Fpicture.jpg",
            "updated": 1537959346,
            "size": 7759448
        }
    ],
```

1. when I try to access `fileReferences.0.mediaLink`, I get an auth error.
2. If I send my token along with the request to mediaLink I have no luck either (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#download-object-json)
3. I tried to use the Google API PHP client https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client, but had no idea how I setup the `new Google_Client()` (I already have my auth token and I expected it to work somehow)

```php
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setAccessToken(['access_token' => $token]);
```

How can I access the media files with my existing auth token? (or do I need a different one?)

To handle the files, I would like to use https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client how can I make that work? Any hint is appreciated

**Edit:** I got some results in debugging the JavaScript SDK

"All" the SDK does is creating the following URL Schema

```
printf('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucket.appspot.com/o/%s', urlencode('projects/-id/logo.png'));
//http[s]://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/<api-version>/b/<bucket>/o/<object-path>
```

You have to sign the call to https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucket.appspot.com/o/projects%2F-id%2Flogo.png with your Auth Bearer token header![1] 
This returns meta data like this:

```
{
  "name": "projects/-id/logo.png",
  "bucket": "bucket.appspot.com",
  "generation": "1537960188874518",
  "metageneration": "1",
  "contentType": "image/png",
  "timeCreated": "2018-09-26T11:09:48.874Z",
  "updated": "2018-09-26T11:09:48.874Z",
  "storageClass": "STANDARD",
  "size": "40437",
  "md5Hash": "MxkOU+6feyYtdEAgKbDgp5A==",
  "contentEncoding": "identity",
  "contentDisposition": "inline; filename*=utf-8''logo.png",
  "crc32c": "o89Y9dQ==",
  "etag": "CJae8pXE2N0CEAE=",
  "downloadTokens": "32c339ff9-7e4a-42a2-890a-428f8f45d378"
}
```

To publicly share your image, add *?alt=media&token=32c339ff9-7e4a-42a2-890a-428f8f45d378*

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucket.appspot.com/o/projects%2F-id%2Flogo.png?alt=media&token=32c339ff9-7e4a-42a2-890a-428f8f45d378`

You don't need the token, if you send the Auth Header!

I couldn't find any mention of firebase or how to deal with my authentication in https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client, so I have no idea if this would have helped me. But I got down to the basics...

Hope this helps somebody and any clearification is greatly appreciated.

**QUESTION** for me to better understand this all:

**What are `mediaLink` and `selfLink` pointing to?**

[1] if the access to storage is public you don't need to sign it.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php ? I'm the author of the library and believe it could be of help, as it has a wrapper around the storage and other Firebase components (https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/storage.html)

Comment: Hey @jeromegamez thanks for leaving a comment. I know your library - but at the time I started the project it wasn't complete yet (storage and auth was missing I think) and - it's embarrassing to say, but my project still has to run on php 5.6. But for anybody else, yes, your library would be the way to go. Thanks for your work!

Comment: is there any example in using firebase storage of your library? Specifically for retrieving the download url on a storage object. The link you provided does not contain such information on how do I use it aside from instantiating it. It does not also seem to provide the functions under getStorage() specifically on how to get download url on storage files. Cheers!

Comment: @RinMinase I have no example at hand right now, but see if my convoluted write up explains it a bit better: https://marcus-obst.de/blog/firebase-storage-and-firebase-auth#tldr and here is my solution how to use firebase auth with php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954047/firebase-auth-js-php/52119600#52119600 - hope that helps

Comment: When you mention the Auth Bearer Token - used to sign, which one do you mean? The "secureToken" returned after email/password login to Firebase ? Or do you get a different auth token ?

Comment: @MetricRat yes, the secure token after you logged in/authenticated to the google service. (I don't completely understand how all the services work together under the hood :))

Comment: @marcus, I have been doing the whole thing through the HTTP Web Component on App Inventor. The secureToken is not supposed to work, but it does ;)